# how to retrieve data from view table in page 1 to display on page 2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to pass view data from shown table on page 1 to page 2. for example, i have table filter used from javascript function. so, after filter the data i wanna it displayed on page 2 also. page 2 is for print and save in pdf file. how to get it parameter so that it displays the data from current table showned?

page1.blade.php (am not sure it is right or not)

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="print">
<table class=" table-autosort table-autofilter " border="1" width="100%" id="save">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>bil</td>
            <td class="table-filterable table-sortable:numeric table-sortable"> faculty</td>
            <td class="table-filterable table-sortable:numeric table-sortable"> programme</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bottom" >

        @foreach($profiles as $profile)
            <tr>
                <td class="number" width="7%%"></td>
                <td class="faculty" width="40%">{{$profile->faculty}} </td>
                <td class="program" width="53%%"> {{$profile->programme}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

page2.blade.php

```
<table width="100%" class="printTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>bil</td>
    <td>faculty</td>
    <td>programme</td>
    <td>student id</td>
    <td>student name</td>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
//possible code here //i dont know how to get it parameter
</tbody>
```

Comment: you mean to say the filtered data, you want to send peage2.blade.php?

Comment: show your javascript function code.

Comment: yes.. that filtered data to be displayed on both page.. for the 2nd page is page as pdf file.. i got my js from this : http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/libsource.php/table/combined/table.js

Comment: Please use any pdf package.

Comment: @VijaySebastian yes. i already use it. it's work. there i call it directly from database. but, here i want data that filtered. i dont know how to get the data after filter in print page.

Comment: pass that filtered data from javascript to your controller and pass to your pdf blade file

Comment: sorry, i don't understand.. does it means i have to edit javascript file ? can you give an example ?